# How to use ffree line length in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I attempted to run some old Fortran code that I "inherited" from a colleague long ago using the gfortran compiler. In principle, I should be able to get what I need from it just by changing some constants corresponding to a model parameter. Upon execution of the script, I get a syntax error

```
Error: Format label 201 on (1) not defined
```

and

```
Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string at (1)
```

which apparently refers to certain command lines being too long. Not having any familiarity with Fortran syntax, my preference is to modify the code as little as possible. I found a stackoverflow posting that referenced the use of

```
-ffree-line-length-n
```

to get around this error. My question is, how do I use this to allow lines of arbitrary length? Is it something that I use as a header in the code itself, or in the gfortran call to execute the code?

Comment: You should show the code but most likely you need `-ffixed-line-length-n`.

Comment: I neglected to provide the other error message,  i.e. unexpected end of format string in format string at (1), which I searched on this site and found that it corresponded to excessively long lines in the code. Perhaps this isn't the case, as I mentioned, I have almost no experience with fortran

Comment: In any case, -ffixed-line-length-n seems to have resolved this problem